# Massive amount number comparison using c#

Tags: c#

Comparison of number sets is too slow. What is more efficiency way to solve this problem?

I have two groups of sets, each group has about 5 millions of sets, each set has 6 numbers and each number is between 1 to 100. Sets and Groups are not sorted and duplicated.

Following is Example.

```
No.     Group A                 Group B
1       {1,2,3,4,5,6}           {6,2,4,87,53,12}
2       {2,3,4,5,6,8}           {43,6,78,23,96,24}
3       {45,23,57,79,23,76}     {12,1,90,3,2,23}
4       {3,5,85,24,78,90}       {12,65,78,9,23,13}
        ...                     ...
```

My goal is compare two groups and classify Group A by maximum common element count in 5hrs on my laptop.

In the example, No 1 of Group A and No 3 of Group B has 3 common elements(1,2,3).
Also, No 2 of Group A and No 3 of Group B has 2 common elements(2,3). Therefore I will classify Group A as following.

```
No.     Group A             Maximum Common Element Count
1       {1,2,3,4,5,6}           3
2       {2,3,4,5,6,8}           3
3       {45,23,57,79,23,76}     1
4       {3,5,85,24,78,90}       2
        ...
```

My approach is compare every sets and number, so complexity is Group A Count * Group B Count * 6 * 6. Therefore it need so many time.

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> Classified = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
foreach (List<int> setA in GroupA)
{
    int maxcount = 0;
    foreach (List<int> setB in GroupB)
    {
        int count = 0; 
        foreach(int elementA in setA)
        {
            foreach(int elementB in setB)
            {
                if (elementA == elementB) count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxcount) maxcount = count;
    }
    Classified.Add(maxcount, setA);
}
```

Comment: Two things you can do straight away is to use HashSets, and to use parallelisation. Then you can look at the Intersect extension method.

Comment: Are you forced to use C#, I mean we are talking about a lot of data.

Comment: @Twenty Nothing wrong with using C# for a lot of data as long as the working set fits in memory. Based on his description that doesn't really sound like that much data.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski yea I know it works, but at least IMO it could be done _more performant_ in another language.

Comment: @Twenty C# is very fast. What language are you suggesting is faster than C# that is suitable for this task? It's close to native speed and it's easy to parallelize.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski depends on how the Data is stored.

Comment: are you able to load either of the groups in memory?

Comment: @Twenty I don't know what you mean. It's being brought into memory in Lists and Dictionaries, as per his code. Loading the data into memory isn't going to be the bottleneck here.

Comment: @RufusL You're right. That's my mistake. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Jawad Sure. I can load all of data to memory. It's not too much for load. size of text file is about 120MB, and use less memory than 1GB

Comment: Meaby this will be intresting for You [link](https://digitalerr0r.net/2010/12/03/parallel-computing-using-the-gpu-tutorial-1-getting-started/)

Comment: Your dictionary is the wrong way around - if you run that code you'll get System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest I can think of is this:

As all your numbers come from a limited range (1-100), you can express each of your sets as a 100-digit binary number `<d1,d2,...,d100>` where `dn` equals 1 iff `n` is in the set.

Then comparing two sets means a binary `AND` on the two binary representations and counting the set bits ([which can be done efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055499/c-sneaky-way-to-count-positive-bits))

In addition to that, this task can be parallelized (your input is immutable, so it's quite straightforward).

Comment: For anyone interested, the bit counting algorithm you are talking about, is named  `Hamming Weight` and the particular version of the one you provided is named `HAKMEM`.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I'll try but I wonder this method can find not only count but also sets.

Comment: @Teddy sure, you can find the actual best-fitting set as well - the numbers are encoded in the binary representation

Comment: @voidengine Your solution is best fit for me. and I also make thread(up to 8). Now total processing time is reduced under 3hrs.

Comment: @Teddy Glad to hear that. Feel free to post another question with your current implementation, it may still be possible to improve the performance.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt - using a [`HashSet<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) and precalculating the range of each set to avoid set-to-set comparisons like `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` and `{7,8,9,10,11,12}` (as pointed out by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127257/matt)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59572329/1364007)).

For me (running with random sets) it resulted in a 130x speed improvement on the original code. You mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572193/massive-amount-number-comparison-using-c-sharp/59572333?noredirect=1#comment105312749_59572451) that

> Now execution time is over 3 days, so as others said I need parallelization.

and in the question itself that

> My goal is compare two groups and classify Group A by maximum common element count in 5hrs on my laptop.

so assuming that the comment means that the execution time for your data exceeded 3 days (72 hours), but you want it to complete in 5 hours, you'd only need something like a 14x speed increase.

---

## Framework

I've created some classes to run these benchmarks:

- `Range` - takes some `int` values, and keeps track of the minimum and maximum values.

  ```
  public class Range
  {
      private readonly int _min;
      private readonly int _max;

      public Range(IReadOnlyCollection<int> values)
      {
          _min = values.Min();
          _max = values.Max();
      }

      public int Min { get { return _min; } }
      public int Max { get { return _max; } }

      public bool Intersects(Range other)
      {
          if ( _min < other._max )
              return false;

          if ( _max > other._min )
              return false;

          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- `SetWithRange` - wraps a `HashSet<int>` and a `Range` of the values.

  ```
  public class SetWithRange : IEnumerable<int>
  {
      private readonly HashSet<int> _values;
      private readonly Range _range;

      public SetWithRange(IReadOnlyCollection<int> values)
      {
          _values = new HashSet<int>(values);
          _range = new Range(values);
      }

      public static SetWithRange Random(Random random, int size, Range range)
      {
          var values = new HashSet<int>();

          // Random.Next(int, int) generates numbers in the range [min, max)
          // so we need to add one here to be able to generate numbers in [min, max].
          // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next
          var min = range.Min;
          var max = range.Max + 1;

          while ( values.Count() < size )
              values.Add(random.Next(min, max));

          return new SetWithRange(values);
      }

      public int CommonValuesWith(SetWithRange other)
      {
          // No need to call Intersect on the sets if the ranges don't intersect
          if ( !_range.Intersects(other._range) )
              return 0;

          return _values.Intersect(other._values).Count();
      }

      public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
      {
          return _values.GetEnumerator();
      }

      IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
      {
          return GetEnumerator();
      }
  }
  ```
- The results were generated using `SetWithRange.Random` as follows:

  ```
  const int groupCount = 10000;
  const int setSize = 6;

  var range = new Range(new[] { 1, 100 });
  var generator = new Random();

  var groupA = Enumerable.Range(0, groupCount)
      .Select(i => SetWithRange.Random(generator, setSize, range))
      .ToList();

  var groupB = Enumerable.Range(0, groupCount)
      .Select(i => SetWithRange.Random(generator, setSize, range))
      .ToList();
  ```

The timings given below are for an average of three x64 release build runs on my machine.

For all cases I generated groups with 10000 random sets then scaled up to approximate the execution time for 5 million sets by using

```
timeFor5Million = timeFor10000 / 10000 / 10000 * 5000000 * 5000000
                = timeFor10000 * 250000
```

---

## Results

- Four `foreach` blocks:

  Average time = 48628ms; estimated time for 5 million sets = 3377 hours

  ```
  var result = new Dictionary<SetWithRange, int>();
  foreach ( var setA in groupA )
  {
      int maxcount = 0;
      foreach ( var setB in groupB )
      {
          int count = 0;
          foreach ( var elementA in setA )
          {
              foreach ( int elementB in setB )
              {
                  if ( elementA == elementB )
                      count++;
              }
          }
          if ( count > maxcount ) maxcount = count;
      }
      result.Add(setA, maxcount);
  }
  ```
- Three `foreach` blocks with parallelisation on the outer `foreach`:

  Average time = 10305ms; estimated time for 5 million sets = 716 hours (4.7 times faster than original):

  ```
  var result = new Dictionary<SetWithRange, int>();
  Parallel.ForEach(groupA, setA =>
  {
      int maxcount = 0;
      foreach ( var setB in groupB )
      {
          int count = 0;
          foreach ( var elementA in setA )
          {
              foreach ( int elementB in setB )
              {
                  if ( elementA == elementB )
                      count++;
              }
          }
          if ( count > maxcount ) maxcount = count;
      }

      lock ( result )
          result.Add(setA, maxcount);
  });
  ```
- Using `HashSet<int>` and adding a `Range` to only check sets which intersect:

  Average time = 375ms; estimated time for 5 million sets = 24 hours (130 times faster than original):

  ```
  var result = new Dictionary<SetWithRange, int>();
  Parallel.ForEach(groupA, setA =>
  {
      var commonValues = groupB.Max(setB => setA.CommonValuesWith(setB));
      lock ( result )
          result.Add(setA, commonValues);
  });
  ```

  Link to a working online demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kxpagh (note that .NET Fiddle limits execution times to 10 seconds, and that for obvious reasons its results are slower than running in a normal environment).

Comment: I realise an answer has been accepted, but there's no harm in providing a solution nonetheless.

Comment: Nice! I was too lazy to write code :-)  - I think in this can be further improved by ditching the foreach and doing index based compares - also, bail early if current elementB item is higher than possible in setA - last, don't lock everytime - have each parallel instance build their own result set then, when done, use AddRange to add them all. You should see a ton more improvement.

Comment: Your test isn't particularly fair because enumerating the values over a hashset is much slower than enumerating values over a list or array so it isn't indicative of his current approach. I just benchmarked doing your hashset intersection method v.s. just using arrays or lists and comparing each element and the latter is much faster than your hashset approach, by a factor of almost 10x in the array case or 2x in the list case. Very small hashsets are slow because of hashing overhead, they just scale better to large sets.

Comment: If you replace your `HashSet<int>` field with an array field and change your `CommonValuesWith` method to brute force the comparisons you will get a much faster implementation, at least with set sizes of 6.

Comment: Your `bool Intersects(Range other)` method implementation is incorrect, it is backwards - it should return false only if `min > other.max` or `other.min > max`. You will find that that test isn't really worth doing when it is done correctly.

Comment: You can see a comparison of intersection method comparisons here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MciskB. The results are a bit different than when I run this locally but either way, the array compare is 9x faster than the hashset intersection approach.

Comment: I added an optimized HashSet approach in the fiddle above and it has the same performance as brute force array comparisons, which is exactly what I expected for sets of this size.

Comment: Array approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FRRojA. That's about as fast as you are going to get. If I change that code to use the optimized hashset approach then it runs slower even though the microbenchmark runs at the same speed, probably due to worse memory locality and caching of the larger hashset based data collection.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski - thanks for your comments. I see this question has also piqued your interest! I'll integrate your comments (and Mike's) into my answer when I'm at a computer again in a few days. Failing that, feel free to integrate your comments into your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to benchmark it with smaller sets but since you're going to have to do `5E6 * 5E6 = 25E12` comparisons, you might as well sort the contents of `5E6 + 5E6 = 10E6` sets first.

Then the set to set comparisons become much fast since you can stop in each comparison as soon as you reach the highest number in the first side of the comparison. Minuscule savings per set comparison but trillions of times over, it adds up.

You could also go further and index the two sets of five million by lowest entry and highest entry. You would further cut down the number of comparisons significantly. In the end, that's only `100 * 100' = 10,000 = 1E4` distinct collections. You would never have to compare sets that have for instance 12 for the highest number, with any sets that start with 13 or more. effectively avoiding a ton of work.

In my mind, this is sorting a lot of data, but it pales in order to the number of actual set to set comparisons you would have to do raw. Here, you are eliminating work for all the 0s and able to abort early if the conditions are right when you do do a compare.

And as others have said, parallelization...

PS: `5E6 = 5 * 10^6 = 5,000,000` and `25E12 = 25 * 10^12 = 25 * 10,000,000,000,000`

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of any algorithm you come up with is going to be of the same order. HashSets *might* be a bit faster, but if they are it won't be by much - the overhead of 36 direct list comparisons vs 12 hashset lookups isn't going to be significantly higher, if at all, but you'll have to benchmark. Presorting might help a bit considering each set will be compared millions of times. Just FYI, for loops are faster than foreach loops on a List and arrays are faster than Lists (for and foreach on array is same performance), which for something like this might make a decent performance difference. If the `No.` column is sequential then I would use an array for that instead of a dictionary as well. Array lookups are an order of magnitude faster than dictionary lookups.

I think you are generally doing this as quickly as possible aside from parallelization though, with some small gains possible through the above micro-optimizations.

How far off from your target execution time is the current algorithm?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now execution time is over 3 days, so as others said I need parallelization.

Comment: By "over 3 days" do you mean it finished after 3 days, or you cancelled the running after 3 days?

Answer (score -1):

I would use the following:

```
foreach (List<int> setA in GroupA)
{
    int maxcount = GroupB.Max(x => x.Sum(y => setA.Contains(y) ? 1 : 0));
    Classified.Add(maxcount, setA);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a LINQ way of doing the for/foreach loops?

Comment: Linq is much more efficient than for loops since linq is using c++.

Comment: @jdweng LINQ does not use C++ and it is not more efficient than for/foreach loops.

Comment: @jdweng LINQ is a group of C# extension methods, not C++. Source code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq)

Comment: Direct links to the source for [`Max<int>(...)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/a.html#6ca1a80e1f22e519), [`Sum<int>(...)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/a.html#17ae8142727f08ee), and [`Contains<T>(...)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/a.html#d1530e4eed8b26b3).